# How do I install mod_rewrite on Cent OS 6.5, i'm using putty

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, putty

I was developing on localhost using XAMP and now that i've finished developing my site, it doesn't work on the output webhost. I think it's because mod_rewrite isn't installed. I'd like to know how to install mod rewrite on cent os 6.5.

I've read on the internet that I should change the document root directive so that it contains 'AllowOverwride All'. There is still no indication that my mod rewrite is working, i'm still getting Not Found errors because the rewriting isn't taking place. pls help thx,

Comment: I used this doc earlier, http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-apache/.

Comment: What version of apache are you running locally and what version is running on your remote host? Enabling mod_rewrite correctly depends on the variant of Apache you are running...

Comment: What der_michael said... But usually as simple as un-commenting `mod_rewrite` in your httpd.conf.

Answer (score -1):

`a2enmod rewrite` is the shell command.

You should restart Apache then with `service apache2 restart`.

Please note, that you should have an appropriate .htaccess file to use it.

Comment: That command would be for Debian or Ubuntu, the OP is using CentOS.